# Stopwatch that can be syncronized across a network of computers?

Tags: networking, sync, timer, stopwatch

Does anyone know of a program, utility, web-app etc, that can be used as a stopwatch to track/display the amount of time that has passed since the user clicked the start button?

The utility must additionally track/display the same amount of time on the other observing computers; i.e. when I click the start button on the first/master computer, the other two computers will receive a packet telling them to start their stopwatches as well; and the same will happen when I click the stop button on the first/master computer the other two computers will receive a packet telling them to stop their timers.

I have seen a similar functionality in [Work Rave](http://www.workrave.org/welcome/) however it cannot be started/stopped.

My intention is to use the functionality to record a screencast that spans multiple computers, and to use the syncro-timer so that I can tell later in video editing when each scene occurred.

**Update**
I found a [link](http://www.pianosoft-freeware.com/atomic-time-sync.htm) to a program which seems to fit the bill (although it doesn't sync between the two computers, it does sync between an atomic clock and the local machine).

[image]

It's not entirely accurate, after a little while the clocks get out of sync, but it's good enough for what I'm trying to pull off here.  It also provides the seconds, which was also a requirement for me.

Comment: Hmm I think this might do the trick: 

http://www.pianosoft-freeware.com/atomic-time-sync.htm

I'll get back to you on if it worked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified the operating system.

I don't know of any prepackaged solution. I'm thinking about two possibilities:

**Solution 1**

VNC protocol using single-window mode: On the master computer set up and start a VNC server supporting single-window mode and launch any stopwatch application. To display the time on other computers use a VNC client and connect it to the VNC server/remote window.

**Solution 2**

If you can work on a terminal it can be done with a stopwatch/counter and netcat to pass the result (e.g. elapsed time) to other computers.

Example:

Stopwatch example using a command-line stopwatch from [here](http://www.jfitz.com/dos/index.html#STOPWATCH) and a netcat for windows binary from [here](http://joncraton.org/files/nc111nt.zip):

Batch file on the master computer (it should be on the same directory as stopwatch.exe and nc.exe).

```
@echo off
stopwatch start > timestamp.txt
pause > null
stopwatch stop < timestamp.txt > elapsed.txt
nc -d -w 1 remote-pc-1 4444 < elapsed.txt
nc -d -w 1 remote-pc-2 4444 < elapsed.txt
...
type elapsed.txt
```

(replace remote-pc-N appropriately, press any key to stop counting)

On the remote computers:

```
nc -L -p 4444
```

Also replace port 4444 if used.

Comment: That netcat is a pretty cool idea...I'm using Windows...in this instance anyway, but I figured I'd ask the question more general like just incase I had to add Linux to the screencast.

Comment: You can get netcat for windows on the web.

Comment: @alfplayer No I'm aware that you can get nc for windows.  But my spyware program gets all angry if I install that.  I guess I could make an exception some how...


Additionally I would need the use of some sort of cmd-line tool for displaying the time.

I tried DOS's "time /T" but "time /T" doesn't display seconds, only hours and minutes.

Comment: I've just added a working example for windows using netcat.

Comment: @alfplayer Sweet idea!  I think I might use it just because it's geekier! ;)

Comment: Graphics and features are not the strength :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you could simply make sure that the clocks on all the participating computers were in sync, and then just use the clock time instead of a stopwatch to identify scenes.  You could easily convert this into elapsed time.

Comment: This would work great if...the clock would show seconds...

Comment: I haven't seen a clock that *wasn't* capable of showing seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this program (haven't tested it myself though):
http://download.cnet.com/MultiTrack-Stopwatch/3000-2350_4-10122220.html

Comment: No network functionality, like most stopwatch applications.

Comment: Right.  That's not what I meant, It needs to connect through the network.

Comment: Oh, sorry :(

I would go with the netcat thing that alfplayer suggested, or possibly VNC.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [link](http://www.pianosoft-freeware.com/atomic-time-sync.htm) to a program which seems to fit the bill (although it doesn't sync between the two computers, it does sync between an atomic clock and the local machine).

[image: Picture of it running on both laptops]

It's not entirely accurate, after a little while the clocks get out of sync, but it's good enough for what I'm trying to pull off here.  It also provides the seconds, which was also a requirement for me.